# Windows protocol installer won't run from a browser

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

We have IT Hit WebDAV Server and IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library running in a Windows development environment.  All is working well except when a user tries to run the protocol installer from the webpage popup message.  The popup says “Select OK to download the protocol installer”.  When I click okay, it opens a new tab with a 404 error.  I can see in the URL that it is looking in the correct folder, and the msi file IS in that folder.

I tried it in 3 different browsers with the same results.  I also tried running the WebDavServer wizard project and get the same results.  The only way I’ve found to get it to run from a browser is through the AjaxFileBrowser app.  In there, the popup message is different and it works when you click the link for the Windows version.

Do you have any ideas for why it’s not running from the browser?

Comment: Windows browser has the lowest privilege of any app. It is for security reasons, and why it can be near impossible to get Perl or Python to work in the browsers directory if doing a loop-back server. Since Windows 7 access rights are strictly enforced by "classes" such as 'creator/system/admin/user' The creator is Microsoft. The IVI Foundation and Net 4 or 4.5 framework can block you, even if you use the CLI. There maybe a workaround for this issue, but some cross-directory actions require a trust certificate from MS.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

1. The MIME-map is not configured. By default IIS has a mapping for .msi and .gz extensions, but maybe it is deleted from IIS for some reason. Here is how to set MIME mapping in web.config:

   <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".pkg" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".deb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".msi" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".gz" mimeType="application/x-gzip" />
   </staticContent>
2. Your WebDAV Ajax Library files are located under the WebDAV path. Your server engine is processing all requests in your code so they do not reach the file system. Just move your static files to some other folder, outside of WebDAV. In case of IT Hit WebDAV samples, the static files are typically located in /AjaxFileBrowser/ folder.

Comment: Moving the installers to be inside of the path of my website instead of in the path of the WebDavServer has fixed the problem.